# Modify Streamlit echarts inside loop without adding new chart

Tags: python, frontend, streamlit, echarts

I want to update my echart with dynamically fetched data, but when I run below code, it adds a new chart to my page.
Unlike `t.text(markdown)` which doesn't add but modifies existing text which is what I want my echarts to be like.

I am using python3.

Is there any argument or API to overwrite existing echarts instead of adding new?

```
    t = st.empty()
    if url:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            markdown, option = render(url)
            t.text(markdown)
            st_echarts(
                option, width="450px", height="350px", key=str(datetime.datetime.now())
            )
```

Comment: Try `t.write(markdown)` in stead of `t.text(markdown)`.

Comment: ```t.text(markdown)``` is not the part of the issue as it is updating instead of adding new texts, I need the echarts to overwrite the old chart in previous loop pass.

Comment: What about clearing the placeholder with `t.empty()` before you write again?

Comment: but t.empty has nothing to do with ```st_echarts```, it is only used for t.text and is working as expected

Comment: Ok. In that case it could be helpful if you post a working code sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I actually found out the solution from https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.empty, the trick is to rerender every element inside ```with placeholder.container():``` instead of using ```st.empty()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `with placeholder.container():`
what ever run under it can be cleared and re-rendered on next loop as below

source: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.empty

```
    placeholder = st.empty()
    if url:
        while True:
            markdown, option = render(url)
            placeholder.empty()
            with placeholder.container():
                st.text(markdown)
                if option:
                    st_echarts(
                        option,
                        width="450px",
                        height="350px",
                        key="gauge" + str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                    )
                else:
                    break
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [streamlit-echarts documentation](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-echarts/):

> key : assign a fixed identity if you want to change its arguments over time and not have it be re-created.

So i guess you should use the same `key` each time?

Comment: Thanks, but I have gone through this documentation, I get this error ```DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='gauge'.
To fix this, please make sure that the key argument is unique for each widget you create.```   assign a fixed identity i if you want to change its arguments over time ->>>> I need to know how to do that actually